# How to get screen reader to read text when triggering QAction?

Tags: qt, accessibility, screen-readers

I'm working on a Qt Widgets app which provides access to commands both through the app's global menu and keyboard shortcuts through a set of [`QAction`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qaction.html) instances. While performing accessibility testing I've noticed that screen readers did not read any text when triggering a `QAction`.  Does anyone know if Qt provides a way to get screen readers to read text strings when triggering QActions?  If it does, could you please provide a minimal working example?

Comment: I'm not familiar with QT but I am with accessibility. Forcing a screen reader to announce something, typically when you have dynamic changes to the page or app, is done via a "live" region. I'm not sure if QT has that concept. I found accessibility document for QT for both [qt5](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/accessible-qwidget.html) and [qt6](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/accessible-qwidget.html). Not sure which version you're using. Perhaps you can achieve it through an [accessible event (v5)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qaccessible.html#Event-enum).