# How to get screen reader to read notifications/announce app state changes?

Tags: qt, accessibility, screen-readers

I'm working on a Qt widgets app which runs a few background tasks that are automatically launched without any direct user input, and I want screen readers to post updates of when these background tasks start and finish. Does Qt provide any way to programmatically get screen readers to emit notifications regarding state change transitions without having to add any dedicated UI element?

Comment: My same comment from [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76202314/how-to-get-screen-reader-to-read-text-when-triggering-qaction) would apply here.

Comment: For windows, I can suggest looking at [my question: now to make windows 10 narrator to speak some text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57922893/make-windows-10-narrator-to-speak-some-text). A static text control with live setting enabled can make Jaws and NVDA speak as well as narrator.